# How do you change the code example font size in LaTeX PDF output with Sphinx?

Tags: python, pdf, latex, python-sphinx

I find the default code example font in the PDF generated by Sphinx to be far too large.

I've tried getting my hands dirty in the generated .tex file inserting font size commands like `\tiny` above the code blocks, but it just makes the line above the code block tiny, not the code block itself.

I'm not sure what else to do - I'm an absolute beginner with LaTeX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I worked it out. Pygments uses a `\begin{Verbatim}` block to denote code snippets, which uses the `fancyvrb` package. The [documentation I found (warning: PDF)](ftp://tug.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf) mentions a `formatcom` option for the verbatim block.

Pygments' [latex writer source](https://github.com/trevorturk/pygments/blob/5d64b54a4aebf853f9a8e815c815465b9a62ae1b/pygments/formatters/latex.py#L311) indicates an instance variable, `verboptions`, is stapled to the end of each verbatim block and Sphinx' [latex bridge](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/164f59b2d946/sphinx/highlighting.py) lets you replace the `LatexFormatter`.

At the top of my `conf.py` file, I added the following:

```
from sphinx.highlighting import PygmentsBridge
from pygments.formatters.latex import LatexFormatter

class CustomLatexFormatter(LatexFormatter):
    def __init__(self, **options):
        super(CustomLatexFormatter, self).__init__(**options)
        self.verboptions = r"formatcom=\footnotesize"

PygmentsBridge.latex_formatter = CustomLatexFormatter
```

`\footnotesize` was my preference, but a list of sizes is available [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Sizing_text)

Comment: The available font sizes are in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Built-in_sizes

Comment: Worked like a charm in sphinx 4.5.0. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

To change Latex Output options in sphinx, set the relevant `latex_elements` key in the build configuration file, documentation on this is located [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-latex_elements).

To change the font size for all fonts use `pointsize`.

E.g.

```
latex_elements = {
   'pointsize':'10pt'
}
```

To change other Latex settings that are listed in the documetntation use `preamble` or use a custom document class in `latex_documents`.

E.g.

```
mypreamble='''customlatexstuffgoeshere
'''
latex_elements = {
'papersize':'letterpaper',
'pointsize':'11pt',
'preamble':mypreamble
}
```

Reading the Sphinx sourcecode by default the code in [LatexWriter](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/164f59b2d946/sphinx/writers/latex.py) sets code snippets to the `\code` latex primitive.

So what you want to do is replace the `\code` with a suitable replacement.

This is done by including a Latex command like `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{\tiny{#1}}}` either as part of the preamble or as part of a custom document class for sphinx that gets set in `latex_documents` as the documentclass key. An example sphinx document class is avaliable [here](https://www.assembla.com/code/astrolib/subversion/nodes/trunk/pysynphot/doc/tsrs/bandpar_comparison/build/latex/sphinx.sty).

Other than just making it smaller with `\tiny` you can modify the `latex_documents` document class or the `latex_elements` preamble to use the Latex package listings for more fancy code formatting like in the StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586572/make-code-in-latex-look-nice).

The package stuff from the linked post would go as a custom document class and the redefinition similar to  `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\begin{lstlisting} #1 \end{lstlisting}}` would be part of the preamble.

Alternatively you could write a sphinx extension that extends  the default latex writer with a custom latex writer of your choosing though that is significantly more effort.

Other relevant StackOverflow questions include

- [Creating Math Macros with Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728292/creating-latex-math-macros-within-sphinx)
- [How do I disable colors in LaTeX output generated from sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241284/how-do-i-disable-colors-in-latex-output-generated-from-sphinx)
- [sphinx customization of latexpdf output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839105/sphinx-customization-of-latexpdf-output)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a modified Verbatim command into your PREAMBLE (Note in this case the font size is changed to tiny)

```
\renewcommand{\Verbatim}[1][1]{%
  % list starts new par, but we don't want it to be set apart vertically
  \bgroup\parskip=0pt%
  \smallskip%
  % The list environement is needed to control perfectly the vertical
  % space.
  \list{}{%
  \setlength\parskip{0pt}%
  \setlength\itemsep{0ex}%
  \setlength\topsep{0ex}%
  \setlength\partopsep{0pt}%
  \setlength\leftmargin{10pt}%
  }%
  \item\MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}%
  \tiny  % <---------------- To be changed!
  \OriginalVerbatim[#1]%
}
```