# How do I change font size in Sphinx latexpdf with anysize or cm-super?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, tex

This isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899283/how-do-you-change-the-code-example-font-size-in-latex-pdf-output-with-sphinx): I'm trying to set a bigger font size for all elements. I managed to make font size 12 instead of 10, but it's still too small to be readable.

Werner suggests in the comments to use `cm-super` font or `anysize` extension. I can's see such packages in Ubuntu. How can I install them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default document classes only allow certain base font sizes (`10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt`). `40pt` is not supported. You need to include packages that supports that font size. Like [`anyfontsize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize) or [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm) or [`cm-super`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super). Then you would use something like `\fontsize{40}{51}\selectfont` in your document, rather than supplying `40pt` as a document class option.

For installation of packages, see [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/5764) or [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764)